# How to install Netis WF2190 driver on Debian?

Tags: debian, drivers

I'm trying to install the driver for Netis WF 2190 usb dongle on Debian but I keep getting an error and I don't know what to do. It's the first time I use linux and I have no idea how to get internet on my machine. I downloaded the script from their site, ran it using sudo sh install.sh but to no avail.

This is the error I get
[image: This is the error I get]

I've seen this asked before but the solution found no longer works for me. Can someone guide me what I have to do? I'm currently using my android phone as tethering so I have internet on my pc

Comment: Could you edit your question so it will be easier to help you out? For example, no pictures instead of text, especially for errors within a terminal. Where did you download the driver?

Answer (score 1):

For people trying to get a driver for Realtek 802.11ac (rtl8812au), I have seen that there was a problem with the usual driver on Linux kernel versions >= 3.10 so a fork was made.

You can download, compile, install and enable it as following on Debian:

```
# apt-get install build-essential git
$ git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
$ cd rtl8812au
$ make
# make install
# modprobe 8812au
```

Comment: `make install` requires sudo, `modprobe` also requires sudo. And you don't mention re-connecting the device. The answer by DingoFx is a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Netis WF2190 03-09-2021 on Debian ver. 11 KDE 64 Bit : installed and working :-)

- Stage 0: connect any other working USB Wifi dongle or LAN cable to estabilish connection with internet.
- Stage 1:

  ```
  # sudo apt-get install build-essential git
  ```
- Stage 2:

  ```
  # git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
  ```
- Stage 3:

  ```
  # cd rtl8812au
  # make
  ```
- Stage 4:

  ```
  # sudo make install
  # sudo modprobe 8812au
  ```
- Stage 5: Disconnect devices from Stage 0
- Stage 6: Connect Netis WF2190 USB and find your network write password.

Info in console should looks like this :

```
$ nmcli device status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE          CONNECTION 
enx045ea43c1135  wifi      connected      Your Wifi
```

Comment: Thank you, everything worked! I would just add that the drivers from the official netis site won't work for Ubuntu 18 (the official support includes only Ubuntu 16).